# Not able to create Azure Container Service type = Kubernetes

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-cli

I am using `Azure CLI 2.0` and I am trying to create `Azure Container Service type Kurbenetes`, with this command (I already created resource group)

```
az acs create --orchestrator-type=kubernetes --resource-group=mi-shared-docker-test --dns-prefix=kube --name=mishareddocker
```

I am getting this error

> waiting for AAD role to propagate..........Could not create a service
>   principal with the right permissions. Are you an Owner on this
>   project?

I can create any vms, webapps etc, but why am I receiving this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error states it pretty clearly, you don't have the right permissions, you should read on the ACS\Kubernetes guide.

I understand you are using AZ, not azure, but the idea is the same, you should have [enough permissions and a service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-deployment#kubernetes-specific-entires-required-in-the-portal) to deploy Kubernetes on Azure.

You need to look specifically at [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/container-service-kubernetes-service-principal).

Comment: i can create any other azure container services with same command, just to change "type" of the framework. i will try to run by administration.

Comment: you need very specific permission to be able to create service principals, I don't think contributor can do that

Comment: it was about the user permission that i have with my current account. i used administrator account, it worked well. thank you for feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There's an typo in your command, `orchestrator=type` should be `orchestrator-type` (dash instead of equals)